# Metadata Extractor for .avi, .mkv, .mp4 files

Tags: c, metadata

I working on metadata of various file formats,extraction of these metadata and changing these metadata. I found some java libraries for these but I want to implement these metadata extractors in C.

Please somebody give me some advice for how to proceed for writing these extractors. I would be really happy if somebody can provide me good links regarding these also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at libavformat, which is part of ffmpeg. It's a C library that parses essentially all important audio and video containers.

Here's the documentation: http://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Comment: It is working fine for mp3 files but it is not extracting properly for mkv, avi files.